# Relay and Apollo Client both can be used?

Tags: redux, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, relay

I'm developing a front-end with `Next.js` where `GraphQL` will be processed from GraphQL API endpoint. `Hasura` is being used as Back-end.

> One of my colleague told me that some developers use Relay along with
> Apollo Client. I told him that why we should use both? If Relay is used then
> stick exclusively to Relay (no need to use Apollo also).

My questions are:

1. Can really both be used in a single project?
2. If i go with only `Apollo Client` what will be the consequences? (i have gone through documentation of  `Relay` but found it really complex to integrate with `Next.js`).
3. Is there really need of `Redux` along with `Apollo Client`? (It's a market place website, lot of data with pages).